# Exception Unhandled by User Code

Tags: c#, exception, object, windows-phone-8

I have a member of a library being declared on the main page of my app:

```
private OpticalReaderLib.OpticalReaderTask _task = new OpticalReaderLib.OpticalReaderTask();
```

It works fine until I want to navigate back to this page at a different time. It brings up the error "An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in OpticalReaderLib.DLL but was not handled in user code".

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

System.Exception is the base class for all Exceptions, so this is a very generic error message.

You could try logging more detail (e.g. exception.Message or exception.InnerException) about the exception that is thrown as part of your investigation. (via a [try-catch](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s5p6.html) statement).

It looks like you're initialising a field, where is this code being executed?

---

**Update due to comment**
As a temporary solution to discover the exception error.

```
    private OpticalReaderLib.OpticalReaderTask _tempTask;
    private OpticalReaderLib.OpticalReaderTask _task
    {
        get
        {
            //code to debug the error that is occuring
            try
            {
                if (_tempTask == null)
                    _tempTask = new OpticalReaderLib.OpticalReaderTask();
                else
                    return _tempTask;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //Log the exception detail here 
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, yes i thought about doing a try catch but it is being declared in the "public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage" and I can't but anything but declarations up there. If there is a form load for a wp8 app I could try put it in there and do try catch?

Comment: Can't you not declare a property with a **get** that includes the exception catching (i stress, this would only be used for debugging the exception. I'll update the question to demonstrate this.

Comment: Another idea, if its a windows phone8 application, do they not have an event that is fired due to any exceptions thrown?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. I managed to get the specific error. It was "Only one instance of OpticalReaderTask is supported at a time and another instance already exists.
   at OpticalReaderLib.OpticalReaderTask..ctor()
   at OpticalReaderDemo.MainPage..ctor()"

But the strange thing is, is that when i return to this page it says _task = null. So it seems like there isn't another instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
  {
    if (_task != null) 
    { 
      _task.Completed -= OpticalReaderTask_Completed; 
      _task.Dispose(); 
      _task = null; 
    } 
    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
  }
```